# What is needed to make angularJS-UI work with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

I am following the [AngularJS](http://angular-ui.github.com/)-UI tutorial and just about the first example I stuck.

I am trying to use a simple tooltip, I have included all js files needed but an exception is thrown by anglularJS-ui module says there is no function called tooltip exists.
I Also included the 'ui' module in my main module but, still not working.

```
Error: ui-jq: The "tooltip" function does not exist
    at Object.compile (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/ui/angular-ui.js:452:15)
    at applyDirectivesToNode (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:4047:32)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3794:14)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3799:14)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3799:14)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3799:14)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3799:14)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3799:14)
    at compile (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3739:29)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:932:9 <a title="ahaaaaaaaa" ui-jq="tooltip" href=""> 
enter code here
```

thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the order of including js files. I am new to JS in general. This was the problem. If you have A.js -> depends on B.js -> depends on C.js. You have to include js like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="C.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="B.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="A.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that you set up **angularjs-ui** and the `'ui'` module correctly (as the `ui-js` directive was understood by the Angularjs compiler), but the reference to `angular-ui.js` is not set up correctly.

You could try `$('body')` and `$('body').tooltip()` in the developer console to check whether `jquery.js` and `jquery-ui.js` is included correctly.